# Visual Studio Code, c/c++ extension

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I am a beginner in VS Code. I already installed C/C++ and Code Runner extensions. Also I have copied the C:\msys64\mingw64\bin to Environment variables.

- Here's the context when I try to run this code in Visual Studio Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){
    int age;
    printf("Enter age\n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("age is %d",age);
    return 0;
}
```

-It shows:

> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:test: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:test:3:
> syntax error collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is there anyone here can help me fix this? Thank You in Advance.

Comment: How do you build? What plugin are you using to build your program? When you try to build and run, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* outputs into your question.

Comment: You sure your file name has proper extension such as .c or .cpp? Make it `test.cpp` or `test.c`. `ld.exe:test: file format not recognized` suggests it has no file name extensions.

Comment: I tried test.c and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the code using File-> Save or by using ctrl+S. then, run the code. It worked for me!

yt link for error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dX-SytgRs4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).